# Voltage source placement

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIYG5L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnNIpE.png)</sup>

I would like to better understand the meaning of voltage source placement. To me, these two subcircuits seem the same, but I am not sure. Are they the same?

Comment: No, they are not the same (equivalent).

Comment: @G36 Thank you.

Comment: In the second case, the voltage source will maintain the stated fixed voltage across its terminals. Thus the top and bottom nodes voltage will see V voltage no matter what exists to the left or to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
[image]

*Figure 1 and 2. OP's original circuits.*

Technically the first one isn't a circuit as there is no circular current path and no current can flow.

The second one is just R1 in parallel with V. The other components are only connected at one end so no current flows in them so they can be omitted without changing the circuit.

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fekaTn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 3. Simplification of revised first circuit.*

Comment: I had stated they were subcircuits. Anyway, I turned them both into the circuits I had in mind, so maybe you can update your answer?

Comment: Your original schematics had value 'R' assigned to each resistor. The modified schematics have are missing all values except one. Are we to assume that all resistors are of equal value? Note that when you omit the component designators R1, R2, etc., that it makes it very difficult to discuss the circuit. In what way did you think the circuits are the same?

Comment: yes, all resistors are the same. I thought I was simplifying the circuit by removing an unnecessary focus on R1 vs R - it's irrelevant whether R1 is different.

Comment: I was confused about how resistors see voltage with respect to voltage source placement, in a case like the above. I now see how circuit 2's voltage is obviously not dropping over R1, so the circuits are not the same. Also G36's comment above clarifies how other resistors would not see the same voltage anyway in circuit 1 on either side of the source.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you! I am still confused about how to treat leads/terminals sticking out of odd ends of the circuit while attached to other elements. Could you then move resistors around as you did?

Comment: No. You assign labels to them such as GND, Input 1, Output 5, etc. Then it's clear that there may be other circuitry attached to those points.

Comment: Right, but otherwise you can - thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In the first circuit, *all* of the current through the voltage source is through the resistor \$R\$. That is, the resistor \$R\$ is in *series* with the voltage source. Importantly, if you *remove* \$R\$ (equivalent to letting \$R\rightarrow\infty\$), the positive terminal of the voltage source is *disconnected* (left floating). Thus, the current through the voltage source is zero if \$R\$ is removed.

However, in the second circuit, removing \$R\$ does not disconnect the voltage source; there remain two branches through which charge flows. So the two circuits are *not* equivalent. In fact, \$R\$ is in parallel with the voltage source

Now, here is something that you might want to put in your growing toolbox of circuit solving 'tricks'.

When you see a resistor in parallel with an *ideal* voltage source, the *only* circuit variable in the rest of the circuit that is dependent on this resistor is the current through the voltage source. That is, in your second circuit, changing the value of (or removing) \$R\$ does not change the voltage across or current through any of the other resistors in the circuit.